# Operator norm for $\max\frac{\Vert x \Vert _1}{\sqrt {x'Cx}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, norms, operator-norms

Suppose $C$ is a $n$ by $n$ real symmetric matrix, and $x\in R^n$.  Is there an operator norm of $C$ for $\max\frac{\Vert x \Vert _1}{\sqrt {x'Cx}}$?

If I decompose $C$ into $A'A = C^{-1}$, It seems this $C$ norm equals to $L_{1,2}$ norm of $A$ as I asked at [math exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469097/max-frac-vert-ax-vert-1-vert-x-vert-2-for-x-neq-0-and-l-2-1-or). But the problem is that the decomposition of $A'A = C^{-1}$ is not unique, and even for one particular $A$, There does not seem an explicit solution [as discussed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469097/max-frac-vert-ax-vert-1-vert-x-vert-2-for-x-neq-0-and-l-2-1-or).

Comment: Does not matter. The reason I wrote this is that it is equivalent to some 2 norm after transformation like $A'A=C$.

Comment: What is the meaning of the expression "an operator norm of $C$ for $\max\frac{\Vert x \Vert _1}{\sqrt {x'Cx}}$" ?